# Calling function in C &pointer to struct

Tags: c, function-call

Good day everyone,

I'm starting to program in C and maybe my question may seem silly but are there any conditions that would prevent method from execution?

Now I'm writing program that uses linked list structure and every thing compiles but after one definite line in code program doesn't call methods.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
        char* toFrom;
        char* meanOfTr;
        int hours;
        int min;
        double price;
        char* note;
        struct node *next;
}travel;

typedef struct list
{
    travel * head;

}list_t;

void add(list_t *list,char toFrom1[], char meanOfTr1[], char note1[],int hours1,int min1,double price1);
void test();

int main(void) {

    list_t *list;
    test();
    list->head=NULL;
    test();
    char* a="London";//then b,c,h,m,p variables declarations and initialization,which doesn't matter 

    add(list,a,b,c,h,m,p);

    return 0;
}
void test()
{
    printf("test\n");
}


void add(list_t *list,char *toFrom1, char* meanOfTr1, char* note1,int hours1,int min1,double price1)
{

    // Some code here

}
```

I use test method which prints "test" to check if program reads this method.
But for some reason after line  "list->head=NULL;"
Program doesn't print anything=>doesn't call method

If someone could explain me why this is happening i would be really grateful.
Thanx in advance

EDIT:I actually solved problem:the problem was that pointer didnt point to actual object,so
when i added

```
list_t l;
    list_t *list = &l;
```

it worked,hope it will help someone with same silly problem(:
Thanks for comments i'll have everything in mind

Comment: Regarding your edit do NOT do that. That's undefined behavior as well! Once the function goes out of scope that memory is no longer available you HAVE to put it on the heap via Malloc!

Answer (score 4):

```
 int main(void) {

   list_t *list;
   test();
   //De-referencing a dangling pointer 
   list->head=NULL;
   test();
```

See my above comment in the code. You're de-referencing a dangling pointer, which is undefined bahavior and probably causing a segmentation fault.

Since you're probably new to c, I will explain a little futher:

`list_t *list` doesn't allocate any memory, all it does is allocates a place on the stack to store the location of allocated memory. So in broader terms, `*list` will point to a location that has enough space to hold a `list_t`. It is up to you to create that space and assign the location to `list`.

You should be doing the following:

```
 int main(void) {

   list_t *list;
   test();
   list =  malloc(sizeof(list_t));
   //Always check for a null return from malloc!
   if(!list){
    perror("Malloc failed");
   }
   list->head=NULL;
   test();
```

Comment: Also remember to `free()` the memory allocated by `malloc` when it is no longer needed.

Comment: That makes sense,and i actually have malloc but deleted it for some reason.
So about freeing memory,when is it necessary to do?I mean it makes sense to do at the end when i'm done with using list or when I want to declare new list deleting previous.Is that right?

Comment: When you're done with the entire list you have to run through it and free it. If you remove a node you have to free the node as well.